# Shape of init parameter in scipy.optimize differential evolution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize, differential-evolution

I do not understand the shape that the algorithm is expecting for the `init` parameter.

In the [help](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html), it says :

> `init` str or array-like, optional
>
> Specify which type of population initialization is performed. Should be one of:
>
> ```
> ‘latinhypercube’
>
> ‘random’
>
> array specifying the initial population.
> ```
>
> The array should have shape (M, len(x)), where len(x) is the number of parameters. init is clipped to bounds before use.

I am passing in something (an array of array) with a shape of (1,17) as the initial value ( = the `init` parameter). So a numpy array of 17 values representing my 17 parameters and am getting the following error message :

> ValueError: The population supplied needs to have shape (M, len(x)), where M > 4.

Trying to dig into it I get this line in the source code :

```py
        if (np.size(popn, 0) < 5 or
                popn.shape[1] != self.parameter_count or
                len(popn.shape) != 2):
            raise ValueError("The population supplied needs to have shape"
                             " (M, len(x)), where M > 4.")
```

The last 2 out of 3 statements in the `if` I understand. You want to make sure that it is an array of array and that the arrays all have the correct size (i.e the number of parameters).

But why does the algo expect the user to give it at least 4 possible starting values ?

Comment: You could make the context of this question clearer, with links, and fuller description.  I had to do some digging to figure what you were asking about.  What initially threw me was your description of a (1,17) 'seed'.  Why 'seed'?  Why 17?

Comment: I am talking about the 'init' parameter of the algorithm so assumed seed made sense in that case : the inital value you are feeding to the algo. It's in the question title only though so will put it in the question.

Comment: edited it to make it clearer hopefully

Comment: Did it not help @hpaulj ?

Comment: @Chapo can you select the answer as approved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `M` has to be greater than 4 is that the `Rand2` evolution strategy needs at least 5 population members. You can read more about that [here.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.473.8325&rep=rep1&type=pdf)